# Can't choose attachments

Tags: battlefield-4

I just unlocked a new scope for my sniper rifle, when when i go to customize the item i unlocked is colored red and unable to select.
I am having this will all scopes unlocks on snipers rifles.
Is this a bug or is this how it should be, if yes how can i use the attachment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This mostlikely isnt a bug.  You might have variable zoom selected in your loadout for that weapon.   Not all scopes can do variable zoom.  Below is my screenshot of my current loadout.  Notice I cannot select Iron sights as I also have variable zoom equipped.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting your attachments and other equipment through the Battlelog interface, unless you're already doing that and not setting them through the game UI.